# Can WMS insert data

Tags: geoserver, wms

WMS can be used to query georeferenced map images ([1]). But can it be used to submit georeferenced map images? For example, WFS can be used to query and insert features ([2]).

[1] http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/reference.html

[2] docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

No, WMS is solely a portrayal mechanism, if you want to add data you need to use WFS-T as you link to in the question. If you want to insert raster coverages you need to make use of the [WCS-T](http://rasdaman.org/wiki/WCSTGuide) [specification](http://docs.opengeospatial.org/is/13-057r1/13-057r1.html).

Comment: But WFS-T can only insert features (i.e. vector data) and not raster maps).